# I modified base_profile with vim. Why do I have "-bash: Setting: command not found"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, terminal

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/us8gZ.png)

I modified the base_profile file with the VIM command, and when I reopened the terminal, it appeared, "- bash: Setting: command not found." This command, what's wrong, how to make it disappear

Answer (score 0):

something wrong with your .bash_profile you just modified.
I bet you have a line started with:

> Setting

Comment: I don't understand. Can you be more specific?

Comment: every time you open a new terminal, .bash_profile will be read. post your modified .bash_profile file will be easy to see what's wrong with it.